# Getting Category Children

Tags: categories, array, terms

i have a problem understanding the get_terms function

All i want is getting all the children of specific category so that it can be listed. But i don't really know how the $args works.

So with this `get_terms(category, $args);`

I tried to use the child_of

```
$args = array(
        'child_of'          => 0,
        'childless'         => false,
);
```

But it gives all the category while i only need the child of a category. Changing the value to "1" gives empty result.

Then i tried the 'slug'

```
$args = array(
        'slug'              => 'on-going',
        'child_of'          => 0,
        'childless'         => false,
); `
```

This gives nothing but "On-going" only.

This is the category tree in my wordpress

[image: category]

The only thing i want is listing all child category of "On-going", that's it....

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `child_of` parameter excepts an integer value of the specific term you need to get descendants from. This means that you need to get the ID from the `On-going` category term and then passing that ID to the `child_of` parameter.

To note, the `child_of` parameter returns **all** descendants of the term passed, this includes direct children and all children of those children etc. If you only need first level children of a specific term, then you need to pass the term id to the parameter `parent`.

If you do not have the exact id, you can use `get_term_by` to get the id and then pass that to `child_of` in `get_terms`

### EXAMPLE

This example shows how to get the term ID if you only have the term name, like in your case `On-going`

```
$get_term_id = get_term_by( 'name', 'On-going', 'category' );
$terms = get_terms( 'category', array( 'child_of' => $get_term_id->term_id ) );
var_dump( $terms );
```

Comment: My apologize before, this script worked, but there's a small problem, it returns everything like description slug, count, and others.. i tried to use the "exclude" arg, but again, i don't know how it works... my webpage doesn't load when i add the exclusion.. or am i doing wrong with this? `'exclude' => description, slug`

Comment: If you need something specific returned, look at the `fields` parameters. You need to understand, `get_terms` returns an object of terms, so you need a `foreach` loop to print the names of the categories

Comment: I'm very sorry of my stupidness, but i don't even understand the script.. i'm using the script you gave me in my previous question.. http://pastebin.com/b3zwDzFG which one should i remove to exclude the whole thing except the title?

Comment: Do you need to build a tree

Comment: Uhm, i wanted to create a page with categories listed in alphabetical order.. http://prntscr.com/7mzf71

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, i found the problem, i only need to remove one line `var_dump( $terms );` and everything works like i wanted. Thank you very much :D

Comment: No problem and my pleasure, ja, I've added the `var_dump()` just to show you the output from the code. Should have told you to just remove that :-). Enjoy